# How to specify types using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to pass id and name to the method and in the method i want to specify the types for the id and name.

below is my code,

```
class SomeAPI extends RestDataSource {
    async getSomething(id: string) {
        const {data} = await this.get(`/${ITEMS}/${id}/`);
        return data; 
    }

    async getItem({name, id}: {name: string, id: string}) {
        const data = await this.getSomething(id);         
        return data;
    }; 
}

const func1 = (parent, someAPI) => {
    const name = get(parent, 'name'); //example 'name1'
    const id = get(parent, 'id'); //example '1'

    const output = await someAPI.getItem(name, id);
}
```

here the id and name that is passed to getItem and getSomething methods are not read properly
the id passed to getSomething is undefined.

i think the type added in getItem method for id and name is not proper and not passed properly to getSomething method.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: You need to instantiate `SomeAPI`

Comment: it works if i just pass id to getItem method like so getItem(id: String) but when using getItem ({id, name}: {id:string, name: string} { //here value id and name is undefined}

Comment: Here you have an example of API class https://catchts.com/api

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was a problem in the way i was using types for the getItem method args.

below works

```
class SomeAPI extends RestDataSource {
    async getSomething(id: string) {
        const {data} = await this.get(`/${ITEMS}/${id}/`);
        return data; 
    }

    async getItem(name: string, id: string) {
        const data = await this.getSomething(id);         
        return data;
    }; 
}

const func1 = (parent, someAPI) => {
    const name = get(parent, 'name'); //example 'name1'
    const id = get(parent, 'id'); //example '1'

    const output = await someAPI.getItem(name, id);
}
```